# Partition a vector in Idris: why can't 0 and m+n be unified?

Tags: idris, unify

I would like to partition a vector in two new vectors.

We cannot know what the length of the individual vectors will be, but the sum of the resulting vectors must be equal to the argument. I tried to capture this property as following:

```
partition : (a -> Bool) -> Vect (m+n) a -> (Vect m a, Vect n a)
partition p [] = ([], [])
partition p (x::xs)
  = let (ys,zs) = partition p xs
  in case p xs of
    True  => (x::ys, zs)
    False => (ys, zs)
```

But Idris reports (pointing to "partition p []") that when elaborating left hand side of Main.partition:

```
Can't unify
        Vect 0 a
with
        Vect (m + n) a

Specifically:
        Can't unify
                0
        with
                plus m n
```

Why is this the case?

To me it seems quite obvious that if "0 = m + n" than m = n = 0. How can if convince Idris of this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remember that [unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29) is a syntactic operation, which in languages like Idris is augmented with straightforward reductions according to pattern-matching. It doesn't know all of the facts that we can prove!

We can certainly prove in Idris that if n+m=0 then m = 0 and n = 0:

```
sumZero : (n, m : Nat) -> plus n m = Z -> (n=Z, m=Z)
sumZero Z m prf = (refl, prf)
sumZero (S k) m refl impossible
```

but this doesn't make the unifier know about this fact, as that would make type checking undecidable.

Returning to your original issue: if I translate the type of your partition into English, it says "for all natural numbers `m` and `n`, for all Boolean predicates `p` over `a`, given a vector of length `plus m n`, I can produce a pair consisting of a vector of length `m` and vector of length `n`". In other words, to call your function, I would need to know in advance how many elements of the vector satisfy the predicate, because I need to supply `m` and `n` at the call site!

What I think you really want is a `partition` function that, given a vector of length `n`, returns a pair of vectors whose lengths add up to `n`. We can express this using a dependent pair, which is the type theory version of existential quantification. The translation of "a pair of vectors whose lengths add up to `n`" is "there exists some `m` and `m'` and vectors with these lengths such that the sum of `m` and `m'` is my input `n`."

This type looks like this:

```
partition : (a -> Bool) -> Vect n a -> (m ** (m' ** (Vect m a, Vect m' a, m+m'=n)))
```

and the complete implementation looks like this:

```
partition : (a -> Bool) -> Vect n a -> (m ** (m' ** (Vect m a, Vect m' a, m+m'=n)))
partition p [] = (Z ** (Z ** ([], [], refl)))
partition p (x :: xs) with (p x, partition p xs)
  | (True, (m ** (m' ** (ys, ns, refl)))) = (S m ** (m' ** (x::ys, ns, refl)))
  | (False, (m ** (m' ** (ys, ns, refl)))) =
      (m ** (S m' ** (ys, x::ns, sym (plusSuccRightSucc m m'))))
```

That's a bit of a mouthful, so let's dissect it.
To implement the function, we begin by pattern-matching on the input Vect:

```
partition p [] = (Z ** (Z ** ([], [], refl)))
```

Note that the only possible output is what's on the right-hand side, or else we couldn't have constructed the `refl`. We know that `n` is `Z` due to the unification of `n` with the index of the constructor `Nil` of `Vect`.

In the recursive case, we examine the first element of the vector. Here, I use the `with` rule because it's readable, but we could have used an `if` on the right hand side instead of matching on `p x` on the left.

```
partition p (x :: xs) with (p x, partition p xs)
```

In the `True` case, we add the element to the first subvector. Because `plus` reduces on its first argument, we can construct the equality proof using `refl` because the addition becomes exactly the right thing:

```
  | (True, (m ** (m' ** (ys, ns, refl)))) = (S m ** (m' ** (x::ys, ns, refl)))
```

In the `False` case, we need to do a bit more work, because `plus m (S m')` can't unify with `S (plus m m')`. Remember how I said unification doesn't have access to the equalities that we can prove? The library function `plusSuccRightSucc` does what we need, though:

```
  | (False, (m ** (m' ** (ys, ns, refl)))) =
      (m ** (S m' ** (ys, x::ns, sym (plusSuccRightSucc m m'))))
```

For reference, the type of `plusSuccRightSucc` is:

```
plusSuccRightSucc : (left : Nat) ->
                    (right : Nat) ->
                    S (plus left right) = plus left (S right)
```

and the type of `sym` is:

```
sym : (l = r) -> r = l
```

One thing that's missing in the above function is the fact that the function actually partitions the `Vect`. We can add this by making the result vectors consist of dependent pairs of elements and evidence that each element satisfies either `p` or `not p`:

```
partition' : (p : a -> Bool) ->
             (xs : Vect n a) ->
             (m ** (m' ** (Vect m (y : a ** so (p y)),
                           Vect m' (y : a ** so (not (p y))),
                           m+m'=n)))
partition' p [] = (0 ** (0 ** ([], [], refl)))
partition' p (x :: xs) with (choose (p x), partition' p xs)
  partition' p (x :: xs) | (Left oh, (m ** (m' ** (ys, ns, refl)))) =
    (S m ** (m' ** ((x ** oh)::ys, ns, refl)))
  partition' p (x :: xs) | (Right oh, (m ** (m' ** (ys, ns, refl)))) =
    (m ** (S m' ** (ys, (x ** oh)::ns, sym (plusSuccRightSucc m m'))))
```

If you want to get even crazier, you can also have each element prove that it was an element of the input vector, and that all elements of the input vector are in the output exactly once, and so forth. Dependent types give you the tools to do these things, but it's worth considering the complexity tradeoff in each case.